# Child Theme Fatal Error

Tags: errors, child-theme

I wanted to create a child theme on my new Wordpress site.

I followed the instructions on the first part of this site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

After doing everything AFTER "How to Create a Child Theme" and before "Template Files", I'm getting the following error message:

**Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare twentyfifteen_widgets_init() (previously declared in /home/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/functions.php:142) in **/home/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/functions.php** on line **141**

(Here, I'm replacing my actual username with the word "username")

I'm not sure really where to start. I followed the directions to a T and am even using the same theme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child theme's `functions.php` file should be an empty file to which you can add code specific to your child theme. It appears you have copied the `functions.php` file from the parent theme instead.

See [this note about `functions.php` in Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php):

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is **loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php**. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)